# How can I make the JXBrowser run in RedHat Linux latest version?

Tags: jxbrowser

I have a valid license for JXBrowser. I am using version jxbrowser-linux64-6.20. When I try to run the program using JXbrowser in Linux, I get the below error.

This is the error I am getting. I am not able to find the below dependencies. How can I fix it?

> 11:29:13 SEVERE: There are next missing dependencies:      browsercore64
> => libgconf-2.so.4, libXss.so.1, libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0, libgtk-3.so.0, libgdk-3.so.0     libbrowsercore64.so => libgconf-2.so.4,
> libXss.so.1, libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0, libgtk-3.so.0, libgdk-3.so.0
> 11:29:13 SEVERE: Failed to start IPC process.
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Missing dependendecies have been
> detected. Check the log for details.     at
> com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.ExternalChromiumProcessLinux.preProcessRun(SourceFile:3162)
> at
> com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.ExternalChromiumProcess.doStart(SourceFile:62)
> at
> com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.ChromiumProcess.start(SourceFile:235)
> at com.teamdev.jxbrowser.chromium.internal.ipc.d.run(SourceFile:196)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is fixed in all JxBrowser versions which embed Chromium 69. Please check the release notes: *[We are glad to announce the release of the new JxBrowser 6.23!](https://jxbrowser-support.teamdev.com/release-notes/2019/v6-23.html)*

You can also install the dependencies manually, however upgrading your JxBrowser library to the latest version is recommended.